# Capture value with correct xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the below XML structure, and i'm trying to capture only the message "`This is a sample message`". But when I read the element /messageText I get the full element inside it. Is is possible to read the message highlighted in bold alone?

```
<messageText heading="Temporary Maintenance message">**This is a sample message** <accessibilityText>close this message</accessibilityText></messageText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you an idea.  Basically are are selecting the child `text()` node of the `messageText` element.  Not the child `text()` node of the `accessibilityText` element.

```
 <xsl:template match="messageText">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

or this

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="messageText/text()"/>
```